# calulating total error based in given variables

Tags: calculus

I was trying to find the maximum error $dR$ in calculating equivalent resistance for two resistors, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$ if the maximum error in each is $0.2$; $R_1=10\ \Omega$, $R_2=20\ \Omega$

started doing the usual $dR_1=dR_2=0.2$, and then did $\displaystyle\ dR = ({∂ R}/{∂ R_1} )d R_1  +  ({∂ R}/{∂ R_2} )d R_2$ and solved for $dR$ but I kind of  realized now that my answer is not somehow correct

I remember solve a very similar example but in that example the maximum error in case each was in percentages so i preceeded by multiplying the individual resistance with the percentages  to obtain the  $d R_1$ and $d R_2$. So was i on the right path or perhaps I am deviating from the normal way of going by things

Comment: Compute the derivative of $r(R_1,R_2) = {1 \over {1 \over R_1} + {1 \over  R_2} }$ and then the estimate is $Dr((10,10)) ((0.2,0.2))$. This is, of course, an estimate. If you want to compute the actual $\max$ error compute $\max(r(10-0.2,10-0.2)-r(10,10), r(10,10)-r(10+0.2,10+0.2))$.

Comment: please can you clarify your point a bit @copper.hat

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f$ of variables $x_1,x_2,...x_n$, if each variable $x_k$ has an associated error $\delta x_k$, then the error on $f$, $\delta f$ is: $$\delta f( x_{1} ,...x_{n}) =\sqrt{\sum\limits ^{n}_{i=1}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} \delta x_{i}\right)^{2}}$$

In your example you have the function $R(R_1,R_2)=(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2})^{-1}$. I'll let you work out the rest.

Comment: Please note: this definition only applies for real, scalar functions of real scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to show that the derivative of $r(R_1,R_1) = {1 \over { 1\over R_1} + {1 \over R_2}}$ is
$Dr((R_1,R_2)) ((H_1,H_2)) = {1 \over (1 + {R_1 \over R_2})^2}H_1 +  {1 \over (1 + {R_2 \over R_1})^2}H_2$.

Hence the first order error estimate would be
$\max_{|H_k| \le 0.2} ({1 \over 4} H_1 + {1 \over 4} H_2) =0.1$.

The actual $\max$ error is given by
$\max_{|H_k| \le 0.2} |r(10+H_1,10+H_2)-r(10,10)| = {284 \over 5143} \approx 0.06$.

The latter can be computed knowing that $r$ is strictly increasing in both variables so one only needs to check the points $(10-0.2,10-0.2)$ and $(10+0.2,10+0.2)$.

Comment: So basically the maximum error is 0.1?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote?

Comment: Yeah I might seem a bit confused with first error estimate and actual error max

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\ge \frac2{\sqrt{R_1R_2}} \implies \ln R \le \ln( {R_1R_2})
$$

Then, apply $\displaystyle\ dR = ({∂ R}/{∂ R_1} )d R_1  +  ({∂ R}/{∂ R_2} )d R_2$ to get the percent expression for the maximum error

$$\frac{\Delta R}{R} \le \frac{\Delta R_1}{R_1} + \frac{\Delta R_2}{R_2}
$$